# Typesetting an equals sign vertically between two labels in a node within a TikZ environment

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a diagram of a simple graph. One of the labels for one of the vertices is $(a^{\prime}, \, b^{\prime}) = (a+n, b-n)$ typeset vertically. It does look exactly what I wanted. My concern is that I used three nodes to do this and several guesses at what the spacing "should be" between them. Is there a way to do this with one node?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}




\begin{document}

\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}

%A part of a line is drawn; ellipses are drawn on both sides of the line segment. Three points on it are labeled.
\draw (-8.5,0) -- (-6.25,0);
%
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at (-3,0){$\ldots$};
%
\draw[fill] (-8.5,0) circle (1.5pt);
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at ($(-8.5,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$(a, \, b)$};
\draw[fill] (-7.5,0) circle (1.5pt);
%A "pin" is drawn between this second point and its label.
\coordinate (label_for_Vertex_2) at ($(-7.5,0) +(0,-0.75)$);
\draw[draw=gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (-7.5,0) -- (label_for_Vertex_2);
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at (label_for_Vertex_2){$(a+1, \, b-1)$};
\draw[fill] (-6.5,0) circle (1.5pt);
%A "pin" is drawn between this third point and its label.
\coordinate (label_for_Vertex_3) at ($(-6.5,0) +(0,-1.5)$);
\draw[draw=gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (-6.5,0) -- (label_for_Vertex_3);
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at (label_for_Vertex_3){$(a+2, \, b-2)$};

\draw (-0.5,0) -- (3,0);
\draw[fill] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at ($(0,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\left(\dfrac{0}{1}\right)$};
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at ($(0,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$(a^{\prime}, \, b^{\prime})$};
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, rotate=90, font=\scriptsize] at ($(0,0) +(0,-0.75)$){$=$};
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at ($(0,0) +(0,-1)$){$(a+n, \, b+n)$};
%
\draw[fill] (3,0) circle (1.5pt);
\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at ($(3,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\left(\dfrac{1}{1}\right)$};
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at ($(3,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$(a^{\prime} + 1, \, b^{\prime} - 1)$};


\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. I focus on the right side of the diagram. It can be rewritten as

```
\draw (-0.5,0) -- (3,0);
\draw[fill] (0,0) circle (1.5pt)
 node[above=0.25cm] {$\left(\dfrac{0}{1}\right)$}
 node[below=0.25cm] {$\begin{array}{c}
 (a^{\prime}, \, b^{\prime})\\
 \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$=$}\\
 (a+n, \, b+n)
 \end{array}$};
%
\draw[fill] (3,0) circle (1.5pt)
node[above=0.25cm] {$\left(\dfrac{1}{1}\right)$}
node[below=0.25cm]{$(a^{\prime} + 1, \, b^{\prime} - 1)$};
```

where you do not need any calc syntax, and the alignment is taken care of by a traditional `array`. The universal node style is set in the options of the `tikzpicture` via `nodes={inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize}`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,positioning}




\begin{document}

\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize}]

%A part of a line is drawn; ellipses are drawn on both sides of the line segment. Three points on it are labeled.
\draw (-8.5,0) -- (-6.25,0);
%
\node[anchor=north,] at (-3,0){$\ldots$};
%
\draw[fill] (-8.5,0) circle (1.5pt)
node[below=0.25cm] {$(a, \, b)$};
\draw[fill] (-7.5,0) circle (1.5pt);
%A "pin" is drawn between this second point and its label.
\coordinate (label_for_Vertex_2) at ($(-7.5,0) +(0,-0.75)$);
\draw[draw=gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (-7.5,0) -- (label_for_Vertex_2);
\node[anchor=north] at (label_for_Vertex_2){$(a+1, \, b-1)$};
\draw[fill] (-6.5,0) circle (1.5pt);
%A "pin" is drawn between this third point and its label.
\coordinate (label_for_Vertex_3) at ($(-6.5,0) +(0,-1.5)$);
\draw[draw=gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (-6.5,0) -- (label_for_Vertex_3);
\node[anchor=north] at (label_for_Vertex_3){$(a+2, \, b-2)$};

\draw (-0.5,0) -- (3,0);
\draw[fill] (0,0) circle (1.5pt)
 node[above=0.25cm] {$\left(\dfrac{0}{1}\right)$}
 node[below=0.25cm] {$\begin{array}{c}
 (a^{\prime}, \, b^{\prime})\\
 \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$=$}\\
 (a+n, \, b+n)
 \end{array}$};
%
\draw[fill] (3,0) circle (1.5pt)
node[above=0.25cm] {$\left(\dfrac{1}{1}\right)$}
node[below=0.25cm]{$(a^{\prime} + 1, \, b^{\prime} - 1)$};


\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Further optimizations are possible.

Comment: Yes, I prefer the spacing obtained from your code. Thanks!